# Edit rollback query

Tags: discussion, editing

Yesterday, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508148/sending-information-with-quantum-entanglement) was asked and I believe the question itself is fine, but my question regards the edits.

I edited the question by paragraphing it and improving the grammar in many areas. The edit I made has since been overridden and rolled back and I am at a loss as to why.

All thoughts / comments appreciated

Comment: Your paragraphing is fine, but I suspect that the OP feels that some of your edits change the original meaning. Maybe ask them in a comment.

Comment: ahhh I can see that, thank you for the suggestion, i'll do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't provide a definitive answer because it was the question owner that rolled back the changes. I can say that your edits were good -- please continue to make improvements like this to questions you see that need it!

Some people do not like the idea of other people editing their text, regardless of the changes made. Perhaps that was the motivation here as well, but that is speculation. If that's the case, hopefully as they participate more, they will get used to how things work here and will appreciate the dedication to clarity and quality the editing process enables.

At any rate, do not worry too much about it. If you think a rollback is particularly problematic, go ahead and flag it for moderator attention. We will look into it. Sometimes it isn't worth losing sleep over and it's best to just move on.

Comment: Frankly, I think that the edits are good and should be rolled back into the post. "Some people do not like the idea of other people editing the text" - then those people can go read the guidance and choose whether this site really is for them. Community editing is how this site works.